# Flutter > Provider > Firebase / Error: The following RangeError was thrown building CheckoutPage

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, provider

I was trying to build checkout screen for my e commerce app i'm trying to develop for test and learn Flutter with provider as state management and firbase as back-end.
when check out screen built this error is shown in log:

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following RangeError was thrown building CheckoutPage(dirty, dependencies:
[_InheritedProviderScope<OrderNotifier>, _InheritedProviderScope<List<Address>>, _InheritedTheme,
_LocalizationsScope-[GlobalKey#f7872], _InheritedProviderScope<CartNotifier>,
_InheritedProviderScope<AuthProvider>]):
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0
The relevant error-causing widget was:
  [38;5;248mCheckoutPage[39;49m
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
[38;5;244m#0      List.[]  (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:166:60)[39;49m
[38;5;248m#1      CheckoutPage.build[39;49m
[38;5;244m#2      StatelessElement.build[39;49m
[38;5;244m#3      ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#4      Element.rebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#5      ComponentElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#6      ComponentElement.mount[39;49m
...     Normal element mounting (24 frames)
[38;5;244m#30     Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244m#31     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount[39;49m
...     Normal element mounting (136 frames)
[38;5;244m#167    Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244m#168    Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#169    RenderObjectElement.updateChildren[39;49m
[38;5;244m#170    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.update[39;49m
[38;5;244m#171    Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#172    ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#173    StatefulElement.performRebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#174    Element.rebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#175    StatefulElement.update[39;49m
[38;5;244m#176    Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#177    ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#178    Element.rebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#179    ProxyElement.update[39;49m
[38;5;244m#180    _InheritedNotifierElement.update[39;49m
[38;5;244m#181    Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#182    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update[39;49m
[38;5;244m#183    Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#184    ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#185    StatefulElement.performRebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#186    Element.rebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#187    StatefulElement.update[39;49m
[38;5;244m#188    Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#189    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update[39;49m
[38;5;244m#190    Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#191    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update[39;49m
[38;5;244m#192    Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#193    ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#194    Element.rebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#195    StatelessElement.update[39;49m
[38;5;244m#196    Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#197    ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#198    Element.rebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#199    ProxyElement.update[39;49m
[38;5;244m#200    Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#201    ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#202    StatefulElement.performRebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#203    Element.rebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#204    BuildOwner.buildScope[39;49m
[38;5;244m#205    WidgetsBinding.drawFrame[39;49m
[38;5;244m#206    RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback[39;49m
[38;5;244m#207    SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback[39;49m
[38;5;244m#208    SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame[39;49m
[38;5;244m#209    SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame[39;49m
[38;5;244m#213    _invoke  (dart:ui/hooks.dart:253:10)[39;49m
[38;5;244m#214    _drawFrame  (dart:ui/hooks.dart:211:3)[39;49m
(elided 3 frames from dart:async)
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

[38;5;248m════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════[39;49m
[38;5;244mThe following RangeError was thrown building CheckoutPage(dirty, dependencies: [_InheritedProviderScope<OrderNotifier>, _InheritedProviderScope<List<Address>>, _InheritedTheme, _LocalizationsScope-[GlobalKey#f7872], _InheritedProviderScope<CartNotifier>, _InheritedProviderScope<AuthProvider>]):[39;49m
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0

[38;5;244mThe relevant error-causing widget was[39;49m
    [38;5;248mCheckoutPage[39;49m
[38;5;244mWhen the exception was thrown, this was the stack[39;49m
[38;5;244m#0      List.[]  (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:166:60)[39;49m
[38;5;248m#1      CheckoutPage.build[39;49m
[38;5;244m#2      StatelessElement.build[39;49m
[38;5;244m#3      ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#4      Element.rebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m...[39;49m
[38;5;248m════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════[39;49m
I/flutter (10118): firebase service placeOrder applied
```

And my checkout page code is:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:propro/src/models/cart_model.dart';
import 'package:propro/src/models/product_model.dart';
import 'package:propro/src/models/user/address_model.dart';
import 'package:propro/src/providers/auth_notifier.dart';
import 'package:propro/src/providers/cart_notifier.dart';
import 'package:propro/src/providers/order_notifier.dart';
import 'package:propro/src/screens/checkout/widgets/checkout_card.dart';
import 'package:propro/src/services/firebase_service.dart';
import 'package:propro/src/widgets/app_bar.dart';
import 'package:propro/src/widgets/primary_button.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class CheckoutPage extends StatelessWidget {
  String productList(BuildContext context, List<Cart> cartItems) {
    String _productList = '';
    for (int i = 0; i < cartItems.length; i++) {
      _productList += (cartItems[i].product.name + ', ');
    }
    return _productList;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    FirebaseUser user = context.watch<AuthProvider>().user;
    List<Address> addressList = Provider.of<List<Address>>(context) ?? [];
    // List<Product> allProductList = Provider.of<List<Product>>(context) ?? [];
    List<Cart> cartItems = context.watch<CartNotifier>().cartItems ?? [];
    List<Product> productItems =
        context.watch<CartNotifier>().productItems ?? [];
    Address address = context.watch<OrderNotifier>().address;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: ZhAppBar(
        title: 'Checkout',
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: ListView(
          // crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            CheckoutCard(
              title: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    'Products',
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline3,
                  ),
                  Text(productList(context, cartItems)),
                ],
              ),
              hasOption: false,
            ),
            CheckoutCard(
              title: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    'Contact Information',
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline3,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'This order will delivered to ${user.email}',
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              hasOption: false,
            ),
            CheckoutCard(
              title: addressList == []
                  ? Container()
                  : Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          'Address',
                          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline3,
                        ),
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            Text(addressList[0].line1 + ', '),
                            Text(addressList[0].line2 + ', '),
                            Text(addressList[0].city),
                          ],
                        ),
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            Text(addressList[0].state + ', '),
                            Text(addressList[0].country + ', '),
                            Text(addressList[0].zip),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
              hasOption: true,
            ),
            CheckoutCard(
              title: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    'Payment',
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline3,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'You can pay cash on delivery',
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              hasOption: false,
            ),
            CheckoutCard(
              title: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    'Delivery',
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline3,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'Deliveryman',
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              hasOption: false,
            ),
            CheckoutCard(
              title: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    'Promo Code',
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline3,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'You can use promotion code here',
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              hasOption: false,
            ),
            CheckoutCard(
              title: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    'Points',
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline3,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'You can earn 999 point with placing this order',
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              hasOption: false,
            ),
            CheckoutCard(
              title: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    'Total',
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline3,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    context.watch<CartNotifier>().total.toString(),
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline1,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              hasOption: false,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 48,
            ),
            Center(
              child: ZhPrimaryButton(
                child: Text('Order'),
                //TODO: Palce an order function
                onPressed: () async {
                  await FirebaseService()
                      .placeOrder(user, address, productItems);
                  print('firebase service placeOrder applied');
                },
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Please help me to solve this problem and best wishes you read my problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot compare list like you did:

```dart
addressList == [] ?  foo : bar;
```

That does not work and will always return "bar".

Instead do:

```dart
addressList == null || addressList.isEmpty ?  foo : bar;
```